# Adding CSRFToken to Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to pass `CSRFToken` with Ajax based post request but not sure how this can done in a best way.
Using a platform which internally checking `CSRFToken` in request (POST request only)

initially I was thinking to add it to header like

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers : {
            'CSRFToken' : getCSRFTokenValue()
        }
    });
});
```

Which will make it available to each Ajax request, but it will not work for my case, since in request `CSRFToken` is still coming as null.

Is there any way I can set `CSRFToken` for all Ajax call dealing with `POST` type

**Edit**
If I do something like this in my Ajax call

```
data: {"newsletter-subscription-email" : "XXX" , 'CSRFToken': getCSRFTokenValue()},
```

Everything is working fine.

*My Issue is, I want to pass `CSRFToken` value as a request parameter and not as a request header*

Comment: So the header is passed but the token is null? What does  `getCSRFTokenValue()` do exactly?

Comment: @RobinJonsson: This is simply getting value for the token

Comment: I am facing the same issue (need to pass CSRF token on Ajax based post but using JS only. I am not familiar with JQuery :(

Comment: what are you returning from getCSRFTokenValue()?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How about this,

```
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
   if (s.type == "POST") {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', getCSRFTokenValue());
   }
});
```

Ref: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118

To pass `CSRF` as parameter,

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file",
            data: { CSRF: getCSRFTokenValue()}
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data: " + msg );
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, though value is getting passed, but it is not available in request, this is how it is being fetched from request at server side `request.getParameter(CSRF_PARAM_NAME)`

Comment: `request.getParameter(CSRF)` in your server side. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks!!, I know this way, but in that case, it means I need to add this to every Ajax call I am going to do in my application

Comment: Yeah! you can use to get the header response csrf token

Comment: This gives an error on s.type

Answer (score 18):

You can use this:

```
var token = "SOME_TOKEN";

$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
});
```

From documentation:

> jQuery.ajaxPrefilter( [dataTypes ], handler(options, originalOptions,
>   jqXHR) )
>
> Description: Handle custom Ajax options or modify existing options
>   before each request is sent and before they are processed by $.ajax().

[Read](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/)

Comment: Thanks, though value is getting passed, but it is not available in request, this is how it is being fetched from request at server side `request.getParameter(CSRF_PARAM_NAME)`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi you use node.js?

Comment: No, I am using Jquery for this

Comment: Thanks! I used to use `$ .ajaxSetup` config, and I had API problems with other servers that refused the request because of the unrecognized X-CSRF-TOKEN header. Now it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

Here is code that I used to prevent CSRF token problem when sending POST request with ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getCookie(c_name) {
        if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            if(c_start != -1) {
                c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if(c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
            }
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: I used your getCookie function. It is useful. thanks

Answer (score 8):

From JSP

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="someURL">
    <input name="csrfToken" value="5965f0d244b7d32b334eff840...etc" type="hidden">    
</form>
```

This is the simplest way that worked for me after struggling for 3hrs, just get the token from input hidden field like this and while doing the AJAX request to just need to pass this token in header as follows:-

From Jquery

```
var token =  $('input[name="csrfToken"]').attr('value');
```

From plain Javascript

```
var token = document.getElementsByName("csrfToken").value;
```

Final AJAX Request

```
$.ajax({
      url: route.url,
      data : JSON.stringify(data),
      method : 'POST',
      headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': token 
               },
      success: function (data) { ...      },
      error: function (data) { ...  }
```

});

Now you don't need to disable crsf security in web config, and also this will not give you 405( Method Not Allowed) error on console.

Hope this will help people..!!

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in node.js with lusca try also this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://test.com",
type:"post"
headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (using jQuery 2.1)

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(elm, xhr, s){
    if (s.type == "POST") {
        s.data += s.data?"&":"";
        s.data += "_token=" + $('#csrf-token').val();
    }
});
```

or this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(elm, xhr, s){
    if (s.type == "POST") {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', $('#csrf-token').val());
    }
});
```

(where #csrf-token is the element containing the token)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in a list of post in a blog, the post are in a view inside a foreach, then is difficult select it in javascript, and the problem of post method and token also exists.

This the code for javascript at the end of the view, I generate the token in javascript functión inside the view and not in a external js file, then is easy use php lavarel to generate it with csrf_token() function, and send the "delete" method directly in params.
You can see that I don´t use in var route: {{ route('post.destroy', $post->id}} because I don´t know the id I want delete until someone click in destroy button, if you don´t have this problem you can use {{ route('post.destroy', $post->id}} or other like this.

```
  $(function(){
    $(".destroy").on("click", function(){
         var vid = $(this).attr("id");
         var v_token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
         var params = {_method: 'DELETE', _token: v_token};
         var route = "http://imagica.app/posts/" + vid + "";
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: route,
         data: params
    });
   });
  });
```

and this the code of content in view (inside foreach there are more forms and the data of each post but is not inportant by this example), you can see I add a class "delete" to button and I call class in javascript.

```
      @foreach($posts as $post)
          <form method="POST">
            <button id="{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right destroy" type="button" >eliminar</button>
          </form>
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above didn't work for me.

I added the following code before my ajax request:

```
function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }

            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: '/url/',
            });
```

Answer (score -3):

Everybody that using: var myVar = 'token', is probably the worst idea. I can print it dirrectly in the console. You need to encrypt on the client side, then decrypt on server side.

Comment: Could you translate that into English?

Comment: You need to learn more about security because you have no idea what you're talking about