# adding protect_from_forgery on an existing rails webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I have a rails app and an api working together.
The application has two years now and  have been developped with the options (in application_controller):

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
#protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

So there was no protection at all against CSRF.

I added <%= csrf_meta_tag %> on all my view layouts and and protect_from_forgery on my application_controller.

The problem is that when my main page is requested, some ajax are executed and they do not contain the CSRF header so I get logout immediately.

How can I introduce the CSRF protection in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Ajax requests to include the CSRF token. You can configure all AJAX requests to send the token by default in jQuery using the following code

```
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
  if (s.type == "POST") {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'));
  }
});
```

(Code taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063821/1478217)). Other JS frameworks probably have similar functionality.

Comment: Started writing this answer then realised there is an almost identical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails). Have flagged as a duplicate

Comment: Great Slicedpan, thanks for your answer and sorry for the duplicate. I have seen other answers but did not really understand that I can add this code ones and have all my ajax request containing the header.
So I need to add this code just after the script jquery tag on my pages