# How to pass Django csrf token in AJAX (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Based on the [w3schools ajax example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) I am trying to make a delete call and then remove the corresponding row from a table. There are plenty of answers here about how to do it using JQuery but I am not doing that. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6868538/214742) which made me write my JavaScript like this:

```
function deleteFullLicense(rowid, objectid) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 204) {
        row = document.getElementById(rowid);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
      }
      else {
        window.alert("Something went wrong. The delete failed.");
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "deleteLicense/" + objectid, true);
    xhttp.send({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'});
}
```

But I get the `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)` message. How should I send the token?

Comment: You need to set is as a header.
Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063612/adding-csrftoken-to-ajax-request

Comment: I have tried to set it as header using: `xhttp.setRequestHeader("csrfmiddlewaretoken", '{{ csrf_token }}')` but that makes no difference. Is there something more that needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out if I called it `X-CSRFToken` instead it worked. Found out about it [here if you want to read more](https://blog.tinbrain.net/blog/vanilla-js-meets-djangos-csrf.html).

```
function deleteFullLicense(rowid, objectid) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 204) {
        row = document.getElementById(rowid);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "deleteLicense/" + objectid, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{ csrf_token }}')
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The header name `X-CSRFToken` actually comes from the parameter [CSRF_HEADER_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-header-name) in Django `settings.py`. When receiving frontend request (e.g. ajax call), Django internally checks header parameters and converts `X-CSRFToken` to `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` which is default value of `CSRF_HEADER_NAME` .

The better approach would be to :

- convert the value of `CSRF_HEADER_NAME`
- render the converted value in previous step, to the HTML template
- in the frontend code (e.g. the HTML template or separate js file), create a custom header with that value and the CSRF token on each ajax call for form submission.

**Here's a quick example** :

In `settings.py`

```py
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "HTTP_ANTI_CSRF_TOKEN"
```

In the view function of `views.py`

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.http.request import HttpHeaders

prefix =  HttpHeaders.HTTP_PREFIX
converted = settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME[len(prefix):]
converted = converted.replace('_','-')
# so the value HTTP_ANTI_CSRF_TOKEN is converted to ANTI-CSRF-TOKEN,
return Response(context={'custom_csrf_header_name':converted})
```

In your HTML template (not good practice, since this is just quick example)

```
<script>
// Note that the value is 'ANTI-CSRF-TOKEN'. when this header name goes to
// backend server, Django will internally convert it back to 'HTTP_ANTI_CSRF_TOKEN'
var custom_csrf_header_name = "{{ custom_csrf_header_name }}";

// the ajax part is almost the same as described in the accepted answer
...
xhttp.setRequestHeader(custom_csrf_header_name, '{{ csrf_token }}')
...
</script>
```