# Getting Intermittent 403 error while making a fetch request from JS

Tags: javascript, django, http-status-code-403, django-cors-headers

I am trying to call a POST API via fetch await in JS which sometimes gives 201 and sometimes it gives 403.

```
const apiCalls = number_arr.map(async (event) => {
                const response = await fetch(`{% url 'base_check_url' %}?number=${event.attrs.value}`, {
                method: "POST",
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
            });
```

APIs are written using django framework

Attaching screenshot of error response logged in console:

[image]

This is an intermittent issue, if I hit the API via JS 10 times, 70% of the time I would get 403. Also, do let me know if any other info is required to debug this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [403 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have read the 403 doc but the point here is some of the requests are going through and some of them are failing with 403.

Comment: This may happen due to csrf_token expiration (debatable). Can you try this and see if it is working [adding csrf_token for ajax reqs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22063612/14080492)